# How to create an osgi bundle of a maven project which could be easily deployed in Servicemix

Tags: osgi-bundle, apache-servicemix

I have a maven project in my local development environment. when I run :
"mvn clean install", it basically creates a JAR file inside the 'Target' directory. 
I have Servicemix up and running. I wanted to know if somehow I could convert this JAR to an OSGI bundle and deploy directly into ServiceMix container.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the maven bundle plugin in your pom, it will embed into the build process and create a bundle of your jar (adds the required OSGi Manifest)

```
  <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
       <extensions>true</extensions>
       <configuration>
       <instructions>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>${bundle.symbolicName}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
            <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
       </instructions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: yeah , i did find this in org.apache.felix. Thanks for your help.